# MongoDB/mongoose: what does sort on nested document do?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, mongoose

Assuming I have a mongoose schema with a nested document `address`:

```
var personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    address: {
        street: String,
        city: String
    }
});
var Person = new mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);
```

Now I can `find` all persons and `sort` them by `address`:

```
var p = new Person();
p.find().sort('address').exec().then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

I observed that the sort on `address` does somehow change the order in which the results are returned, but I could not figure out how.

How does sorting on a field that holds a nested document affect the result?

Comment: If you sort on a whole subdoc like that, it's basically sorting on that subdoc's binary representation. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Nothing. I just recognized it doesn't give an error and it does have an effect. I wondered how it works and couldn't find information about it, so I asked. ;)